# Mongo query with conditions on the nested structure(collection)

Tags: python, database, mongodb

I have a collection with a `nested fields` like this:

```
student: {
name: banana,
meetings: [
{grade: AW, key1, group: A, time: ISODate("2018-09-25T14:08:00.729+0000")},
{grade: AW, key2, group: A, time: ISODate("2018-09-24T14:08:00.729+0000")},
{grade: BC, key2, group: B, time: ISODate("2018-09-25T14:08:00.729+0000")},
{grade: BC, key3, group: B, time: ISODate("2018-09-24T14:08:00.729+0000")},
{grade: BD, key4, group: D, time: ISODate("2018-09-25T14:08:00.729+0000")}
  ]
}
```

Would like to pick up for each `meeting`, pick up `name`, and its **`latest grade`** info, if `group` is in ['A', 'B', 'C']. 
For instance this collection I would like to get:

```
student: {
name: banana,
meetings: [
{grade: AW, key1, group: A, time: ISODate("2018-09-25T14:08:00.729+0000")},
{grade: BC, key2, group: B, time: ISODate("2018-09-25T14:08:00.729+0000")}
  ]
}
```

It seems like using unwind and `$group` is a potential solution. However the collection is very `huge`, which makes the `$group` not even possible. Can anyone give me some hints on this? Thank you.

Comment: For that you can check `pipeline` in lookup.

Comment: @IftekharDani can you make some examples which ones to use? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$filter` in `$project`.

```
db.getCollection('students').aggregate([
{ 
  $project : 
  {
     'student.name' : 1,
    'student.meetings' : {
      $filter: {
        input: "$student.meetings",
        as: "item",
        cond: { $in: [ "$$item.group", ["A","B"] ]}
      }
    }
  } 
  }])
```

Note: Tested in `MongoDb GUI` `Robo3T`

Comment: Thank you very much, this `filter` function is very interesting. However, because I have some more complicated structure in the database, so this one still didn't work as what I want.

Comment: I have queried as per your example in `question`

Comment: Yes you are right. I am very grateful for your help. But i have some confidential data which is not allowed to post here.

Comment: One more question on your answer, how can I select the latest grade record for each grade value? e.g. `grade: AW, key1` and 'grade: AW, key2' will led to only `grade: AW, key1` because it's the latest one for `grade: AW`

Answer (score 0):

Since this is from a `huge collection`, `group` method will trigger `memory` issue. So I tried to use the following query, and with some `post processing` in `python` to get the results. Please let me know if you have better suggestions. Thank you :)

```
db.getCollection("***").aggregate([
{$unwind: {path: '$meetings'}},
{$match: 
  {
    'time':{$gte: new ISODate("2018-10-01T00:00:00Z")} , 
    'group': {$in: ['A','B']} ,
    'meetings.time':{$gte: new ISODate("2018-10-01T00:00:00Z")}
  }
},
{$addFields: {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "grade": "$meetings.grade",
    "time": "$meetings.time"
}},
{$project: { "_id": 1, "grade": 1}}
]);
```